# Navigate from UIViewController to UITabbarController and than Tabbar to Another View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

In Storyboard rootViewController is LoginViewController After Login I am going to UITabbarController.
on Tab Bar Controller there is list. after click on cell I am going to another ViewController. this process work right but problem at back button 
At the end when I click on back button it directly navigate to Login View Cotroller instead of UITabbarController

here is Screen shot of storyboard[image]

[image]

Login button Method

```
- (IBAction)SDBtnLogin:(id)sender
  {
    SDTabFavorites *sdTabFavViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabVC"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:sdTabFavViewController animated:YES];
   }
```

Did select method of SDTabFavorites ViewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     SDDetailViewController *sdDetailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SDDetailViewController"];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:sdDetailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

After Navigate to SDDetailViewController and try try to back then directly goes to login view controller.

Comment: Are you using default back button of `UINavigationController`??

Comment: yes I am using default back button

Comment: @VinodJadhav i think there is no back button for tabViewController... and using going Back to  TabViewController.. So that is the problem.

Comment: Your `SDDetailViewController` is next view after `SDTabFavorites` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never push VC from login/register to home screen. Always show it in model seque. You need to replace

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sdTabFavViewController animated:YES];
```

to

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:sdTabFavViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The Home screen should not have any back button to go back to login/register page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it help me in Xamarin.iOS, I changed :

```
HomePageViewController homePage = 
this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("HomePageViewController") as 
HomePageViewController;
NavigationController.ShowViewController(homePage, this);
```

to

```
HomeTabController homePage = 
this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("HomeTabController") as 
HomeTabController;
await NavigationController.PresentViewControllerAsync(homePage, true);
```